# "Incorrect Meteor executable" in Webstorm 10 on Windows 8.1

Tags: windows, meteor, exe, webstorm

I am trying to figure out where to find my meteor executable on Windows.

When pointing Webstorm to the "meteor.bat" in my Users\myUser\AppData\Local.meteor folder Webstorm 10 does not accept "meteor.bat" as the executable.

EDIT: I am using Meteor for Windows.

Where should I point it to?

Comment: It's fairly wacky, but I had to point WebStorm to the `meteor.bat`, see the error, then restart it, then it worked. Check if that works for you too!

Comment: Yes, only in some parts though. WebStorm accepts the `meteor.bat` but I still cannot start everything out of WebStorm.

Comment: Well, my last option is updating everything (WebStorm went 10.1 the third of April, and also Meteor...)

Answer (score 5):

I was able to fix this issue by setting the meteor.bat path in the WebStrom global settings.

Open the WebStrom settings dialog:
[image]

Type `meteor` in the top left search box:
[image]

On the right hand side, set the meteor executable path and save.

Now you should be able to create meteor app

Comment: Also, you need to restart webstorm.